# javax.swing.JFrame doesn't contain setDefaultCLoseOperation

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jframe

I'm trying to add a `setDefaultCLoseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` line in my code. But it seems that for some reason `javax.swing.JFrame` doesn't contains `setDefaultCLoseOperation`.   Netbeans put a red exclamation sign in the line with the "setDefaultOperation" and i don't know why.

This is the code I have.

```
package defaultPackage;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class elemgraf_2_jframe extends JFrame {

public elemgraf_2_jframe(){
   super("Lineas Cruzadas");
   MiPanel2 dibu= new MiPanel2(Color.white , Color.blue);
   setSize(500,500);
   setLocation(100,100);
   setDefaultCLoseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
   add(dibu);
}

public static void main (String args[]){
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new elemgraf_2_jframe().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}    
}
```

Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: Capital 'L' - change to lower case?  It's - setDefaultCloseOperation()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.
.
.

setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   

.
.
.
```

You've misspelled the method.

Comment: Thank you so much!!  I spent hours!! My god!